# Check if input is empty for each method

Tags: c#

I have a class which has a list constructor input and has a lot of functions returning doubles. An empty list is a valid input in some cases but almost all functions return _isEmpty ? double.NaN : _myList.Something.

Is it possible to optimize the repeating check?

```
public class test
{
private readonly List<double> _myList;
private readonly bool _isEmpty;

public test(List<double> mylist){
_myList = myList
_isEmpty = myList.Count == 0;
}

public double GetFirst()
{
return _isEmpty ? double.NaN : _myList.First()
}

public double GetLast()
{
return _isEmpty ? double.NaN : _myList.Last()
}

public double GetSum()
{
return _isEmpty ? double.NaN : _myList.Sum()
}
```

...

Comment: Optimize for what reason? Did you notice some problem with that code?

Comment: Note that you could/should use `double?` instead of `double` and return `null` if the list is empty.

Comment: Exceptions are your friend.

Comment: There is not a problem with the code. I just don't like the repeating _isEmpty? Double.NaN : other return. 
Whatever repeats should be automated, in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, make a private function that wraps the functionality

```
private double GatedReturn(Func<double> nonEmpty)
{
    return _isEmpty ? double.NaN : nonEmpty()
}
```

and call it like so:

```
public double GetFirst()
{
    return GetedReturn(() => _myList.First());
}

public double GetLast()
{
    return GetedReturn(() => _myList.Last());
}

public double GetSum()
{
    return GetedReturn(() => _myList.Sum())
}
```

(Note: you dont actually need the anonymous function - that can be written like `return GetedReturn(_myList.Last);`)

If you're wondering why take a `Func<double>` and not, say just a `double` it is because an empty list will not be able to read `First`/`Last` so it defers this call until you know the list is not empty (or at least your property says it isnt!).

It does beg the question though, why do you need another field indicating if the list is empty?!

Comment: Don't even need the anonymous functions e.g. `return GatedReturn(_myList.First);`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay true, but somewhat less clear for those not used to programming. Especially as the OP originally mixed up method calls `Last()` and a non-exitstant property `Last`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I was looking for. I would vote it up but I don't have enough points yet:-(